# What is the name of the movie similar to “War of the Worlds” but like vampires?

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, vampire, alien-invasion

This movie is similar to “War of the worlds” but it is not war of the worlds! In it there are walkers that have domes underneath (I don’t remember if it was one or two) and go capture humans. They also take humans from them or ones still running and stab them for their blood which they extract. I saw this many years ago and I do not remember anything else, but if I see it I think I’ll remember. Please help me, this has been bugging me for months!

Comment: Colour or b&w? American, British etc? Live action/animated? Any additional information you can provide may be useful.

Comment: It was in color and I remember it is a movie, not a book, and the alien machines were the ones who threw down the people and stabbed them for blood. At one point, people destroy one of the machines and an alien falls out. I do not remember if it was a tripod, quadropod, or anypod.

Comment: About your statement, “many years ago”: this means different time spans for different people. If you are in your 20s a decade might be “many years ago” to you, but I would not describe it that way. You need to edit your question and add a lot more *specific* details. We shouldn’t have to pull it out of you piece by piece.

Comment: Also, this sounds like it could be Tobe Hoppers *Lifeforce*: http://www.imdb.com/media/rm3941412608/tt0089489

Comment: I have no idea how long ago it was made, just that i watched it about 10 years ago. Also, the aliens DO NOT take the blood. One of the legs of the walkers are what takes the blood. Thank you all for your help, but I doubt I will be able to find it. I have been searching for almost a year, but have yet to find it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It could, in fact, be an adaptation of War of the Worlds. Wells' Martians did suck blood from humans and inject it into their own veins, though this hasn't always been shown in adaptations.

Of recent adaptations, there are [the Spielberg one with Tom Cruise](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407304/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), a [made-for-video one from 2005](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0449040/), and a made-for-video sequel, [War of the Worlds 2: The Next Wave](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1183733/) (2008). There are literally dozens of other adaptations for TV and the screen; check [this list on IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/find?q=war%20of%20the%20worlds&s=tt&ref_=fn_al_tt_mr).